# How can I select a whole table updating only some rows?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm on PostgreSQL 9.4.4.

I have a table `messages` that stores my chat. Its field `read` is set to 1 when an user receives each message.

When a client requests all the messages, I would like to `SELECT * FROM messages` and `UPDATE messages SET read = 1` only on certain rows (where `user_id` is not equal to the requester's id).

This query returns only the updated rows, so that's not what I'm looking for.

```
UPDATE messages SET read = 1 WHERE user_id != $1 RETURNING *;
```

Is there a way to do this with a single query?

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, what if you combine both your query like

```
UPDATE messages SET read = 1 WHERE user_id != $1;select * from messages;
```

Well then, in that case consider wrapping your queries inside a stored procedure and call that from your `node.js` code behind like below [**Note: it's a sample proc code and may not have exact similar syntax per postgresql]

```
create procedure sp_updatedata (parameter int)
as
begin
UPDATE messages SET read = 1 WHERE user_id != parameter;
select * from messages;
end
```

Comment: The `pg` module for node.js doesn't like multiple queries. I get `[error: cannot insert multiple commands into a prepared statement]`.

Comment: `CREATE PROCEDURE` doesn't exist in postgreSQL. I've tried creating a function, but I didn't manage to make it work.
For now I'll just use a transaction (I followed this [wiki article](https://github.com/brianc/node-postgres/wiki/Transactions)).
I would have loved a single query, though. Let's see if somebody else suggests a better approach... Thanks anyways!

Comment: @CarloVespa, you can try creating a `Function` which returns a `refcursor` means a resultset. See a good example here http://www.sqlines.com/postgresql/how-to/return_result_set_from_stored_procedure

Comment: Yea, but you still have to keep the transaction open to use that cursor (`FETCH ALL IN 'cursor_name'`), meaning that I still wouldn't be able to use a single query.